# Can I put affiliate links in my DS?

Tags: discussion, developer-story, external-links

Would it be acceptable to put affiliate link in my DS(Developer Story), or is that spam?

Example 1: I have a book that I used to learn the fundamentals Swift, great read!
Can I have the link to the book be an affiliate link?

Example 2: I made a milestone that involved company X that has payed users and they have an affiliate program. Can I have an affiliate link for the website?

Comment: Personally, I'd consider that part of your profile, and in general affiliate links are [allowed in profiles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48785/amazon-affiliate-links-are-not-inserted-into-user-profiles/49101#49101). Can't say for certain, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We currently don't prevent affiliate links from being added to your profile, so that extends to the Developer Story as well since it's also part of your profile.

At this time, there are no plans to prevent you from including affiliate links in your story.