# Traditional view of Developer Story gives dofollow links to users with <2k rep

Tags: bug, status-completed, developer-story, external-links, traditional-view

Stack Overflow "give users the benefit of a non-nofollow link in their profile (when they achieve 2k reputation)". Anything less would "open up a world of potential linkspam exploits" — [Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6905/can-we-not-rel-nofollow-links-in-profile-about-me-for-users-with-3000-rep/11358#11358)

But... I was playing around with the Developer Story, and realised that the "Traditional view" gives me a dofollow (non-nofollow) link to my personal site, even though I only have 353 rep on Stack Overflow.

[image: Traditional Developer Story showing dofollow link to personal site]

What's to stop some low-ranking unscrupulous individual from spamming Stack Exchange with [lots](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/1703216?view=Cv) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/1703216?view=Cv) [links](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/1703216?view=Cv) to their [traditional view](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/1703216?view=Cv) in order to (indirectly) pass on as much juicy PageRank as possible to their personal site?

Uh, hypothetically, of course.

Comment: Seems like ALL the links in both developer story views do not apply the `rel="noreferrer"` attribute, including links to companies, recommended readings, project links, personal website, etc.. Maybe the spammers already know this, e.g.: [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/336475), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390293), [3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392551), [4](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392054), etc.

Comment: Yes, spammers already know this. CVs have been a *major* abuse vector for spam for quite some time now. I had discussed this with Shog9, and was trying to work with him to plug up some of these holes, but then, you know, things changed. This is a quick, simple, obvious fix.

Comment: I see two potential solutions: 1) clamp down on what's allowed in the developer story and make liberal use of nofollow, noreferrer, etc., particularly for low rep users; or 2) give everyone full control over their own developer story, but mark links _to_ it as nofollow (essentially treating CVs as an external link, albeit hosted by Stack Exchange).

Comment: Looking at this now. Yes, dev story has been an avenue for abuse and we do have prevention mechanisms in place (some inspired from prior discussions with Shog) but it looks like this was overlooked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the report, I've made changes to the traditional view so that links are rendered consistently with the timeline view, change is going out to production now